# Phase in stepper motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor

I was going through Nema 17 stepper motor, and I saw that it was given 1.2 A/phase. What does the phase mean in a stepper motor?

Answer (score 1):

The similar meaning as "a `pole`" in AC induction or synchronous motor, NOT the same meaning as "a `phase`" in AC induction or synchronous motor.

Each of the 2 below images has 4 phases (x, \$\overline{x}\$, y, \$\overline{y}\$ are all individual `phases`. A, A', B, B' are all individual `phases`)

[image]
[image]